# QT5 QML C++ - Can´t build

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

It´s my first time trying to connect c++ to Qml and I cannot find my error.

The error I get is the following:

```
..\FINAL\patientenmodel.cpp(17) : error C2678: Bin„rer Operator '<<': Es konnte kein Operator gefunden werden, der einen linksseitigen Operanden vom Typ 'QList<Patient *>' akzeptiert (oder keine geeignete Konvertierung m”glich
```

What am I missing? Here is my code.

First the `Patient` class header:

```
class Patient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString getName READ getName WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)

public:
    explicit Patient(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Patient();

    //Name als String
    QString getName() const;
    void setName(const QString &);

private:
    //Patienten Name
    QString s_name;

signals:
    void nameChanged();
};
```

The corresponding `Patient` source file:

```
Patient::Patient(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

Patient::~Patient()
{

}

//Name
QString Patient::getName() const
{
    return s_name;
}

void Patient::setName(const QString &n)
{
    if (s_name == n)
        return;

    s_name = n;
    emit nameChanged();
}
```

Now the `PatientModel` header:

```
class PatientenModel:public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ~PatientenModel();
    PatientenModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    void addPatient(const Patient &patient);

    // QAbstractItemModel interface
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;

private:
    QList<Patient*> m_patients;
};
```

Here is the `PatientModel` source:

```
PatientenModel::~PatientenModel()
{

}

PatientenModel::PatientenModel(QObject *parent):QAbstractListModel(parent)
{

}

void PatientenModel::addPatient(const Patient &patient)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_patients << patient;
    endInsertRows();
}

int PatientenModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_patients.count();
}

QVariant PatientenModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    role=0;

    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_patients.count())
        return QVariant();

    return QVariant();
}
```

Finally the `main`:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);

    //Patient Objekt anlegen
    Patient pObjP1;
    pObjP1.setName("Hans");

    Patient pObjP2;
    pObjP2.setName("Marta");


    //Model mit Objekten anlegen
    //PatientenModel pModelObj;
    //pModelObj.addPatient(pObjP1);
    //pModelObj.addPatient(pObjP2);


    //QAbstractListModel *model = qListPAtienten;


    //Liste registrieren bevor das QML File geladen wird.
    //qmlRegisterType<DataEntryModel>("org.example", 1, 0, "DataEntryModel");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're trying to append a Patient to a QList<Patient*>. That won't work. Make it a QList<Patient>.

Comment: thx for your fast answer, i tried this before but then i got the following error:

patient.h(28) : error C2248: "QObject::QObject": Kein Zugriff auf private Member, dessen Deklaration in der QObject-Klasse erfolgte.
        D:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore/qobject.h(463): Siehe Deklaration von 'QObject::QObject'
        D:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore/qobject.h(107): Siehe Deklaration von 'QObject'

Comment: @Matthias can you provide an English translation of those error messages?

Comment: If i tried this: QList<Patient> m_patients; in the Model.h
 
error: patient.h(28) : error C2248: "QObject::QObject": No access to private members , which declarated in the QObject class.

Comment: Ah, Patient is a QObject. If you really need it to be, then you can't use them as values indeed, and need to make it addPatient(Patient*).

Comment: @Frank 

I tried the following:

in Model.h
    void addPatient(Patient *patient);
    QList<Patient> m_patients;

in Model.cpp
void PatientenModel::addPatient(Patient *patient)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_patients << *patient;
    endInsertRows();
}

But i get the same error

Comment: Sure you get the same error, you inverted the problem! In the header put `addPatient(Patient *patient); QList<Patient*> m_patients` whereas in source  put `m_patients << patient;`. Apart from that QML integration should occur via [registration as a context property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html) NOT as a new QML type (commented code) since the model is filled in C++ context.